# How to discover hidden elements with Cypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, ui-automation, cypress

I am working on a page that has hidden elements until you hover over the element before it becomes visible.
The issue is my scripts fail whenever I get to the code. See the error below.
[image]

This is the screenshot of how the hidden element looks before and after.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cypress does not have cy.hover() command, but it has a few [workarounds](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/hover.html#Workarounds). Have you tried them to make the element appear?

Comment: realHover() is there npm install cypress-real-events

Answer (score 0):

**To hover elements in cypress**

```
 cy.get('.selector').invoke('show') / cy.get('selector').trigger('mouseover')
```